# Locating original record and updating all records to show it

Tags: sql

Say I have a table that has the following columns:

```
AutoID (PK, int not null)
TaskID (FK, int, not null)
PreviousTaskID (int, null)
ProductID (int, not null)
ProductVersion (int, 0)
```

Data is entered as follows:

Whenever a product is created then a new row is added into the table, along with its associated TaskID, version number (ProductVersion), and the TaskID associated with the previous version (PreviousTaskID).

For example:

```
New product: TaskID = 123, ProductID = 1, ProductVersion = 1, PreviousTaskID = null.
New version: TaskID = 234, ProductID = 1, ProductVersion = 2, PreviousTaskID = 123
New version: TaskID = 456, ProductID = 1, ProductVersion = 3, PreviousTaskID = 234
```

Now what I need to do is create a table with a new column entry that shows the original TaskID e.g.

```
TaskID = 123, ProductID = 1, ProductVersion = 1, PreviousTaskID = null, OriginalTaskID = 123
TaskID = 234, ProductID = 1, ProductVersion = 2, PreviousTaskID = 123, OriginalTaskID = 123
TaskID = 456, ProductID = 1, ProductVersion = 3, PreviousTaskID = 234, OriginalTaskID = 123
```

Assuming that there are multiple products, what SQL do I need to perform this retrospective search and update?

Comment: What have you tried?  If you want to do code-by-request then you should hire a consultant.  Stack Overflow is for assistance with specific issues.

Comment: SQL is outside of my comfort zone. I'm after pointers on where to start. Suggesting that I hire a consultant isn't helpful. I can select all records with the same ProductID, but how do I find the first TaskID and set the OriginalTaskID field in all records to that value when I can't perform loops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following steps:

1. Create the New Table
2. Insert the First Table values into the New Table (leaving OriginalTaskID = 0 or NULL)
3. Update the OriginalTaskID like this:

   ```
   update NewTable
   set OriginalTaskID = 
     (select f.TaskId
      from firstTable f
      where f.ProductId = n.ProductId
        and f.PreviousTaskID = 1)
   from newTable n
   ```

Comment: By `Product Version` do you mean `Product ID`?

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a try. So SQl runs that recursively as a loop?

Comment: @ChrisBD it will run the same select for all the rows selects in the update. So, it'll run for all rows because the select of the update does not have any restrictions :)

Comment: @ChrisBD : Recursion is only needed if you link records by TaskID.  This example links them by ProductID and so no recursion is needed.

Comment: It could also be `and f.ProductVersion = 1` instead of `and f.PreviousTaskID = null`.

Comment: @AndriyM I think all that and that made it wrong :P Thanks m8, it's corrected!

Comment: Oops, I didn't mean to say you were wrong with `f.PreviousTaskID = null`. I only suggested my condition as an alternative. In fact, I think the two are equivalent in the context of this problem: the first product version will certainly have `PreviousTaskID = null`, and vice versa, the version without the previous task ID will always be the first one. Sorry about the confusion!

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'll mark this as the answer as it fits my question. Unfortunately, I've come across a lot of data rows where PreviousTaskID has been left as NULL when it shouldn't have been.

Comment: @AndriyM yeah, you are right, I was right with that restriction as well. My head is not the same in this last couple of days :P I need to sleep morrrrrrrrrrre